# dns zone configuration incorrect

Tags: bind, dns-zone, named-conf

i'm trying to ping mail.example.com  but failed. base on my below zone configuration.

Did I configure anything wrong?

```
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
@   IN  SOA serverad.example.com.   root.example.com. (
                232       ; serial
                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                )
IN  NS  serverad.example.com.
serverad        IN      A   172.17.5.121
121     IN  PTR serverad.example.com.

mail    IN  A   172.17.5.22
22      IN  PTR mail.example.com.
```

Comment: Your PTR records don't belong in your forward zone; you should have a separate reverse zone for those. Could you clarify what you mean when you say the ping doesn't work? Does the name resolution fail, or does the name resolve to the IP and the ping results in no reply?

Comment: actually i wan to ping "mail.example.com"  but it said unknown host.

Comment: i thought it should reply 172.17.5.22.  i'm just started to learn dns zone.  but, according to tutorial. should work.

Comment: Where are you pinging from? Does that machine use the BIND server as a DNS server?

Comment: ya. i'm using this bind server as DNS server.  actually i tried on my local bind server, it reply the same error message.

Comment: I would recommend not to use ping to test name resolution. Try `nslookup mail.example.com 172.16.16.16` where 172.16.16.16 should be replaced with the IP address of the BIND server where this zone exists.

Comment: ** server can't find mail.example.com: NXDOMAIN

Comment: may i know is it possible that will cause by named.conf?

Comment: I don't see a problem with your definition of the `mail` `A` record specifically, so at this point I think you have to troubleshoot your zone or your BIND configuration in general. There isn't enough information here to say why it's not working. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: ignoring out-of-zone data error while change the "@" to example.com.  is it related to this?

Comment: Hi, i found out why, my zone has key in wrong,and my zone is already exist in samba4 dynamic create zone,i need to use samba-tool dns add or dns management tools in window

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out why, my zone has key in wrong,and my zone is already exist in samba4 dynamic create zone,i need to use samba-tool dns add or dns management tools in window